# Is there a way to search all file names in a PHP project in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, search

I'm using [Eclipse PDT for PHP](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/).

Let's say I have an error in "rightsManager.php on line 145", and I have **hundreds** of files in dozens of directories in my project, **what is the fastest way to go to that file and line number?**

I can search through the *text* of all files with **CTRL-H** but how do I quickly search through the *file names*? (like CTRL-H in **Firefox** where it gives you a search box for past urls).

## Answer:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, thanks Paul!

[image]

Comment: Isn't that functionally part of the file manager of your OS?

Comment: yes, I could find the file in windows explorer, but that would be more clicking and searching, I want to stay in eclipse, press CTRL-H, type e.g. "rights/145" and pop to that line, would expedite debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+R should pop open a resource finder in any flavour of Eclipse, type your filename pattern and you'll get your file in seconds. You can jump to a line with Ctrl+L

[alt text http://www2.cwcweb.com-a.googlepages.com/openresource.png](http://www2.cwcweb.com-a.googlepages.com/openresource.png)

[Nice summary of other shortcuts here.](http://www.n0sl33p.org/dev/eclipse_keys.html)

Comment: One hidden feature of Ctrl+Shift+R is that as long as you type everything in lower case, the search will be done case-insensitive. When you have typed at least one capital character, the search is done case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

What about `Ctrl+Shift+M` to search through the functions names, or `Ctrl+Shift+R` to search through the files names ?

Then, `Ctrl+L` to go to the line you want.

Unfortunatly, I don't think you can do "goto file + goto line" using only one dialog :-(

For more things like these, open the "Navigate" menu ;-)

*Edit : If you are looking for ways to do things faster, you might also be interested in the [Eclipse PDT “tips” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169689/eclipse-pdt-tips) question I asked a while ago ;-) (there are not many answers, though :-( )*

Answer (score 1):

If you open up search with Ctrl+H, leave your text criteria as * and then you fill out the file name pattern field with the name of the file you're looking for, it will search by filename. However, it will not point you to a line number.[Search http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4597/searcht.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4597/searcht.png)

Comment: thanks, I had that one closed (click Customize button lower left to open), finding the file fast gets me 80% there, then CTRL-L for line number

Answer (score 0):

(warning: shameless marketing ahead)

The Open Resource (Ctrl+Shift+R) is a great solution indeed. If you are looking for something more powerful, we have an Eclipse plugin called [nWire for PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php). It also provides quick-search, but you can search for everything: files, classes, variables, fields, methods, functions... everything.

Also, once you find the file you were looking for, you can select it and see all its' references in other files. You might find it useful.